# C++ 20 module cannot be loaded due to a configuration mismatch

Tags: c++

Im experimenting with C++ 20 Modules, using cmake 3.27.4 and clang 16.0.6.
I have two libraries, one depending on the other. Where the first imports a module existing in the other.

The import fails with the message:

```
error: POSIX thread support was disabled in PCH file but is currently enabled
error: module file XXX.pcm cannot be loaded due to a configuration mismatch with the current compilation [-Wmodule-file-config-mismatch]
```

The CMake files sort of look like this:
First:

```
add_library(XXX STATIC)
target_sources(XXX PUBLIC
        FILE_SET cxx_modules TYPE CXX_MODULES
        BASE_DIRS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}"
        FILES src/xxx.ixx)
```

Second:

```
add_library(YYY STATIC)
target_sources(YYY PUBLIC XXX)
```

i tried importing the c++ module defined in one library to the other, but instead of the module being imported i got the error message above, saying the import failed because of configuration mismatch.

I tried adding posix threads to the first library without success

Comment: AFAIK modules are not fully supported by clang yet. Check out [this table](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html#cxx20).

Comment: Thanks Marek, but this is not (entirely at least) because of lack of support. The type of module I'm using is supported by the toolchain and other test has proven to work, in this case though one module is being compiled with different parameters (in my case, one with posix threads and the other without) which hinders the module from being loaded

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my own question here for others thats in the same situation.

The problem here is that a BMI (module) compiled with different/incompatible options wont be loaded.

In this case the module `XXX` I was trying to load was not compiled with PTHREADS, since the module `YYY` was compiled with PTHREADS the import failed.

By compiling `XXX` with PTHREADS the two modules became compatible.